# How to embed code snippets in Medium?

Tags: embed, medium

Is it possible to embed code snippets on Medium?

Comment: What about inline code snippets?

Answer (score 55):

You can add a code block by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> on Mac)

Source: https://medium.com/help-center/writing-128f049a7ad#b41a

Comment: Is there a way to enable syntax highlighting when inserting code like this?

Comment: I've only looked briefly, but it doesn't look like it. You might be better off asking in a separate question rather than here though.

Comment: Is there anything for inline code snippet?

Comment: @Anwar Medium has no support for inline code at this time unfortunately

Comment: Is there a button for this?

Comment: No button I'm afraid, just the keyboard shortcut @ShaharOr

Comment: why the hell something used a lot by coders around there doesn't sport a simple freaking button for this formatting option? Why's it a hidden feature? What other hidden features are there? :thinking_face:

Comment: Thank you, this works, unlike the triple backtick they mention in their docs. Amazing that this is a hidden feature, so stupid.

Answer (score 33):

[Medium also supports github gists](https://medium.com/the-story/yes-we-get-the-gist-1c2a27cdfc22) which include syntax highlighting.

> A lot of folks have asked for GitHub gist support. Now we have it. Simply paste your gist URL into your Medium story and hit return.
>
> You can still also highlight text and hit command-6 for code snippets. Ctrl-6 on Windows.

Comment: Looks like this is only possible for public gist's and does not work for secret gist's.

Comment: Not true, see https://medium.com/@kirkstrobeck/handlebars-template-assembly-69367dbc98fb

Comment: As I found we would need to use the JavaScript URL from the Gist embedded code to make this work.

Answer (score 4):

just use the ``` to create a new code block.

Comment: How about the comment section?

Answer (score 2):

I found the help article here:
https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/224550008-Code-blocks-inline-code

Basically:

1. **type ``` or `** (triple or single backtick) in new line will trigger code block or inline code accordingly. (the keyboard shortcut mentioned by others works too)
2. For **syntax highlighting**, it suggests **Github Gists, Codepen.io, or JSfiddle**

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can also go to gist.github.com . Type/paste your code there and paste the link in Medium, then press enter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to embed full working code, you can use https://www.codiva.io. Codiva is registered as an embedly provider, so just paste the project URL, medium-embedly-codiva will do the remaining magic.
Codiva supports Java, C and C++. For example, https://medium.com/@jayaprabhakar/poorly-researched-clickbait-articles-in-dzone-cca19d1d0999

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste code from editors like Webstorm or VS Code. It should create a code block.

Answer (score 0):

> You can also add a code block by typing ``` (three backticks) on a new line, or create an inline bit of code by typing a single backtick at the beginning and end of the code. (Or select the text, and type a single backtick).

Source: https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/225168768-Write-post