# How to embed a Google spreadsheet (or any kind of tables) in Medium?

Tags: google-sheets, embed, medium

I tried to embed a Google spreadsheet in Medium without success. I could get the post the title but not the data. Knowing that I used the "publish" feature of Google spreadsheet.

If not possible, is there any other tables tool that can do that?

Comment: The current app name for the Google spreadsheet editor is Google Sheets.

Answer (score 4):

A published Google spreadsheet is an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe). At this time, Medium does not allow iframes ([source](https://twitter.com/medium/status/395615602892492800)).

I think the best you can do to include a table is to

1. Convert it into text (here's a [handy tool](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for that).
2. Post this text as a code block: see [How to embed code snippets in Medium?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/66453/how-to-embed-code-snippets-in-medium)

Naturally, this copy-pasting will create a static snapshot of your spreadsheet, unlike embedding which would allow changes to propagate.

Comment: The table gets broken for long rows unfortunately, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Well, then I would embed a fragment of table to give users an idea of what's in there, and put a link to published sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Medium now allows to embed a table via [Airtable](https://airtable.com).

*Source:* [Medium: Embed Tables With Airtable](https://medium.com/@yourfriends/embed-tables-with-airtable-9ba30944514b)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using [Sheetsu Table](http://sheetsu.com/table) creator. It’s a creator where you copy a shareable link from a spreadsheet, customize table and add your outcome link directly into your story on Medium. Works perfectly. Here is [an example](https://blog.sheetsu.com/show-table-on-medium-ba0be0c16c59) :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you RowShare, an online interactive table that allows automatic update. It comes with an iframe code which you just need to copy to Medium. 
I wrote an article which explains about this. Please have a look: https://www.rowshare.com/blog/en/2017/10/10/How-to-Embed-Tables-in-Your-Website

Answer (score 0):

A streamlit dataframe can be connected to google sheets and embedded into a medium blog. Have a look here: https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/databases/public-gsheet and here for free hosting of your streamlit app: https://streamlit.io/cloud

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/159119)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).