# How to embed single Linux command or a single line of code block in a Medium blog from Linux?

Tags: medium

I have looked at the answer to this question: [How to embed code snippets in Medium?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/66453/how-to-embed-code-snippets-in-medium)

Both the answer to that question, and the [official documentation of Medium](https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/224550008-Code-Blocks) says the  way to embed a code-block is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>.

But that's only for Windows, and there's no mention of how to embed code-block in Linux. In my machine Ubuntu 15.10 the above keyboard combination is not working for embedding a code block.

I am using Google Chrome.